# Codeigniter tag filter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I got 3 tables :

tables: **tags, tag_relations, products**

- **tags**           : tag_id, tag
- **tag_relations**  : tag_id, product_id
- **products**       : product_id, product

For an example I have 3 tags on (gold, yellow, bright) these tags are related to product.
I need to filter my result with ActiveRecord in codeigniter, so I would retrieve products that have ALL of these tags.

## tags

```
 tag_id   tag

  1      black
  2      yellow
  3      gold
  4      bright
  5      dark
```

## tag_relations

```
 tag_id  product_id

  1      57
  2      101
  3      101
  4      101
  5      52
```

## products

```
 product_id  product

  52         TV
  57         Laptop
  101        Speakers
```

Comment: Post your tried efforts with relevant code.

Comment: post tables all columns

Comment: please check now, hopefully its more clear :) thanks!

Comment: will you pass more than one tag to filter?

Comment: yup, and all these filters need to match, if one of them does not, then that product would not come up

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
$this->db->select('t.tag_id,t.tag,p.product');
$this->db->from('tags t');
$this->db->join('tag_relations tr','tr.tag_id = t.tag_id','left');
$this->db->join('products p','p.product_id = tr.product_id','left');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

not sure because not run this query :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  p.product
FROM products p
  LEFT JOIN tag_relations tr
    On tr.product_id = p.product_id
  LEFT JOIN tags t
    ON t.tag_id = tr.tag_id
WHERE t.tag IN('gold', 'yellow', 'bright')
```

### SQL Fiddle Demo

OUTPUT

```
|  PRODUCT |
|----------|
| Speakers |
```

And this is active record

```
$where  =   array('gold', 'yellow', 'bright');

$this->db
    ->distince()
    ->select('p.product')
    ->from('products p')
    ->join('tag_relations tr','tr.product_id = p.product_id','left')
    ->join('tags t','t.tag_id = tr.tag_id','left')
    ->where_in('t.tag',$where)
    ->get()
    ->result();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for response, but this is not what I needed. 
I need all these three to match, so if you pass 
       `$where  =   array('gold', 'yellow', 'bright', 'black');`

This still does return, even though there are two colors now, it needs to match all tags in $where, that's why **where_in** would not work correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
foreach($filters as $filter)
{
    $i++;
    $this->db->join('tag_relations tr'.$i, 'tr'.$i.'.product_id = products.product_id');
    $this->db->where('tr'.$i.'.tag_id', $filter);
}
```

did the work